# Why this JS id does not work for multiple items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a 2 buttons and an image. When ever I press any of the buttons the image fades out. like this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5wBuV/6/

the problem is that this is working only for the first button and the second one does not work. It might be a simple mistake but I am really beginning in JS.

```
    $("#clickedButton").click( function() {
    $("#hide").fadeOut("slow");
    });
```

Comment: You cant have multiple elements with the same id. Use class instead.

Comment: @NixR.Eyes Can you tell me how to do it please ?!

Comment: Use class attribute in your selector. Here's the update. http://jsfiddle.net/5wBuV/8/

Answer (score 4):

id of an element must be unique, if you use ID selector jQuery will return only the first element with the id.

In your case if you want to add same event handler to a set of elements, you can use a common class attribute and then use [class-selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
<!-- The button -->   
<a href="#" class = 'clickedButton'>
    <img src="http://www.kwvs.pepperdine.edu/playbutton.png" />
</a>
<a href="#" class = 'clickedButton'>
    <img src="http://www.kwvs.pepperdine.edu/playbutton.png" />
</a>
```

then

```
$(".clickedButton").click( function() {
    $("#hide").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZM7uM/)

Comment: Although he should probably be using "on" in stead of click. $(".clickButton").on("click", function() { $("#hide"),fadeOut("slow");});

Comment: @Swordfish0321 both will have same result, unless the OP is planning to use dynamic elements... `.click(...)` is a short hand for `.on('click', ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Using id selector will only return zero/ one object.

If you want to refer to more than one object, use class selector. Like:

```
$('.clickedButton').click(function () {
    $('#hide').fadeOut('slow');
});
```